# how can i add an admin for a rails app , to modify users ,and apps content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, web-deployment

i have recently finished michael hartl's tutorial for rails 4 . 
he created a migration for adding an admin column in users.

```
    class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
    end
    end
```

and then he changed the seed file to seed the users

```
   User.create!(name:  "Example User",
   email: "example@railstutorial.org",
   password:              "foobar",
   password_confirmation: "foobar",
   admin: true)
```

but creating admin like this to manage the content of a web app will not be secure for  these reasons:
1.anyone who can look in the code of seed file will eventually find out about admin user
2.if i create an admin page , where users can signup and become admin,that would be malicious practice as well.

so what should be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

On production you would probably log into your server, open the Rails console and create your first admin manually.

Comment: my app is deployed to heroku ... how should i approach to this situation

Comment: heroku run rails console

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who can see into seed file, can see into schema.rb file where he can find out what kind of security features you have - and, most probably will be able to see into other files code like controller where you check for this "admin" flag or any other fancy authorization-related code.

I would recommend though to either:

- set this password to something random and use "forgot password" functionality to reset it
- require to change password when "password_change_required" flag on user will be set to true (so just add another field to user with this "password_change_required", and after user logs in he is requested to change password)
- setup first user via `rails c` on your production machine

And, most important of it all, dont forget to filter out "admin" parameter in users_controller (or wherever you are doing updates to users).

Comment: so basically rather than assigning a user in "seed.rb" file, i should do it in rails console?................. hmm!! i think that will be a good practice. ... how do i assign or make a user an admin when app is already delployed on heroku. does heroku lets you open irb for interacting with app. or if i make a user an admin in my console and then deploy it . it will still be an admin in heroku.  //thanks for comment//

Comment: on heroku you can run rails console with `heroku run rails c` on your machine, remember though you need to have heroku-toolbelt installed